# Which package is best for making app for Wi-Fi scanning and connect to Wi-Fi network in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have to develop app which Scans for available Wi-Fi networks, then connect to these network,

So For this which package if best?

I have Flutter version 3.0.4, wifi_iot: ^0.3.17,

I used above package but its deprecated, So please any Suggestion to which package should I use?

Below is My Code to scan networks but i can not get any networks.

```
getWifis() async {
        isEnabled = await WiFiForIoTPlugin.isEnabled();
        isConnected = await WiFiForIoTPlugin.isConnected();
        htNetworkResult = await loadWifiList();
        setState(() {});
        if (isConnected) {
          WiFiForIoTPlugin.getSSID().then((value) => setState(() {
                ssid = value!;
              }));
        }
      }
    
    Future<List<WifiNetwork>> loadWifiList() async {
        List<WifiNetwork> htResultNetwork;
        try {
          htResultNetwork = await WiFiForIoTPlugin.loadWifiList();
        } on PlatformException {
          htResultNetwork = <WifiNetwork>[];
        }
    
        return htResultNetwork;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is not the problem here. It's the changes that had came with the android versions. You cannot get list of available Wi-Fi networks on the Android devices that are running on Android 10 or above. You can get the floating Wi-Fi panel that shows all the available Wi-Fi networks.

It can easily be done through native channel.

On the native side, you can make changes like this:

```
private val CHANNEL = "flutter. Native/wifi"
    private lateinit var channel: MethodChannel

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        var wifiManager = this.context.applicationContext.getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
        val mBluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
        channel = MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL)
        channel.setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            if (call.method == "wifi"){
                println(!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled)
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q){
                    val wifiManager: WifiManager =
                        this.context.applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
                    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled)
                }
                else{
                    val panelIntent = Intent(Settings.Panel.ACTION_INTERNET_CONNECTIVITY)
                    startActivityForResult(panelIntent, 0)
                }
            }
```

Make sure to make these changes in the MainActivity class.

Then on the flutter side, you can create a function and then call it on button press:

```
getWifi(){
static const Channel = MethodChannel('flutter. Native/uninstall');
await Channel.invokeMethod('wifi');
}
```

Hope it helps. :-)

Comment: can you please describe more details.